# Missing btc in personal wallet

Tags: theft, copay

I am missing BTC in my personal copay wallet.

https://live.blockcypher.com/btc/address/1HJKHvzxRjKFDcHopyLqLgL3RhWAGipgYY/

https://live.blockcypher.com/btc/tx/7b99ec55d467578ec3fece195e21a2922f974768210d9ec349dbcd9c57a768e4/

Answer (score 1):

If you did not send the Bitcoin's then someone has access to your account or private key. This could happen many ways, if you have ever shared your login details with anyone or, your backup seed, logged in through internet cafe's or strange computers or if your phone or computer are hacked to name a few possibilities.